How to do circle packing in an irregular polygon
I have been trying to pack as many circles in a polygon as possible.
Having found this - Controlled circle packing with Python -
I though it would be a useful code if the checkBorders function was to be changed to one that fits better.
I have tried solving that using physics and forces: when a ball crosses the edge, we find the normal of that edge and bounce back the ball at the same angle.
However, my code does not seem to be working at all, could somebody perhaps help with this?
This is what I have so far
def checkBorders(self, ball):
    pointy = Point(ball.x, ball.y)
    polygon = Polygon(self.POLY)
    is_inside = polygon.contains(pointy)

    if not is_inside:
        min_distance = float("inf")
        closest_edge = None
        for i in range(len(self.POLY)):
            p1, p2 = np.array(self.POLY[i]), np.array(
                self.POLY[(i + 1) % len(self.POLY)]
            )
            edge = p2 - p1
            edge_normalized = self._normalize(edge)
            ball_to_p1 = np.array(ball.position) - p1

            projection = np.dot(ball_to_p1, edge_normalized) * edge_normalized
            distance = np.linalg.norm(ball_to_p1 - projection)
            if distance < min_distance:
                min_distance, closest_edge = distance, (p1, p2)

        normal = np.array(
            [
                closest_edge[1][1] - closest_edge[0][1],
                closest_edge[0][0] - closest_edge[1][0],
            ]
        )
        normal = self._normalize(normal)  # Normalize the edge normal
        # Calculate the reflection vector
        dot_product = np.dot(ball.velocity, normal)
        ball.velocity = ball.velocity - 2 * dot_product * normal
        ball.update()

Output - this is what I get and the circles are now not moving at all.

Can you explain how the code is not working as expected? Is the simulation unstable, i.e. do the circles gain energy and eventually escape the polygon or fail to settle into an equilibrium? Does collision detection / resolution work correctly? Can you show a screenshot of the initial and final state?

Thanks for the question - it seems the code does not work now at all - the circles are mapped within the polygon but they are not moving. I added the screenshot to the post too.

I think one issue here is that you are not accounting for the endpoints of each edge in your collision implementation. In other words, you are effectively treating each edge as an infinitely long line. This is especially problematic when the collision mesh is non-convex. See my answer here for how to calculate the minimum distance or displacement vector to a line segment.
